# Tablesorter custom parser with dashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I've got a mix of integers, doubles and couple of dash characters and I need to sort it with this plugin.

Here is how one of my data tables might look like :

```
5,841
-
121
-
1,102
-
-
743
-
144
9,065
-
2,230
200
6,450
209
0
1
45
54,463
162
8,222
```

I want the output to be like this :

```
0
1
45
121
162
144
200
209
743 
1,102 
2,230 
5,841
6,450 
8,222
9,065
54,463
-
-
-
-
-
-
```

Or :

```
-
-
-
-
-
-
0
1
45
121
162
144
200
209
743 
1,102 
2,230 
5,841
6,450 
8,222
9,065
54,463
```

I've tried this parser, not quite working :

```
jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: "commaDigit",
  is: function(s, table) {
    var c = table.config;
    return jQuery.tablesorter.isDigit(s.replace(/,/g, ""), c);
  },
  format: function(s) {
    return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/,/g, ""));
  },
  type: "numeric"
});

$('#table_list').tablesorter({
        headers : { 
                0 : {sorter:'commaDigit'},
                1 : {sorter:'commaDigit'},
                2 : {sorter:'commaDigit'}
            }
    });
```

**Update :**

I don't know if this is relevant but my data is placed like this :

```
<tr>
<td><span>122</span><td>
<td><span>12,2</span><td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the dashes to be treated as a maximum, just set them to that value (`Number.MAX_VALUE`). Otherwise you could make it negative (`-Number.MAX_VALUE`). Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/T9Bc3/4/).

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: "commaDigit",
  is: function(s, table) {
    return false; // no need to test since you're manually setting it
  },
  format: function(s) {
    return ($.trim(s) === '-') ? Number.MAX_VALUE : $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/,/g, ""));
  },
  type: "numeric"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems to work fine

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bc3/)

you might want to check that your `<table>` has a `<thead>` section with the headers otherwise the plugin won't work.

if you're using asp.net and a GridView you'll have to explicitly set it to use `<thead>` (see: [How can I use jquery tablesorter with an asp.net gridview? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978990/how-can-i-use-jquery-tablesorter-with-an-asp-net-gridview))

Comment: don't see any difference when the numbers have a `<span>`, http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bc3/1/

Comment: thanks for your response please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bc3/2/ , the downsort puts dashes before the zero

Comment: how should it sort the dashes?